# Check in jquery if tinymce contains specific word

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I want to check in tinymce textarea if the text within contains specific word and change its color to red if so.

```
$(".show_words").click(function(){
$("#content tinymce.get('textarea_id').getContent():contains('word')").css("color","red");
});
```

Unfortunatly, nothing happens. How to write this order correctly? Thanks

EDIT:
HTML:

```
<div id="content">

<input type="button" value="show words" class="show_words"/><br/>
<textarea name="drug_description" id="textarea_id" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: That JavaScript code should be out of the string

Comment: And when will you check this? when clicking in the "show words" ?

Comment: show the html you are targetting

Comment: @Alexander could you clarify it?

Comment: @mik.ro `.get('textarea_id').getContent()` doesn't belong in your selector string.

Answer (score 1):

`tinymce.get('textarea_id').getContent()` Returns a string of html (make sure to actually set `textarea_id`). You can use vanilla javascript to search this.

```
if(tinymce.get('textarea_id').getContent().search("word")) {
    $("#content").css("color", "red");
}
```